# How can I evaluate $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(m+n)!}{n!}\right)^a \frac{(-x)^m}{m!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have the infinite sum

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{(m+n)!}{n!}\right)^a \frac{(-x)^m}{m!}$$

with $a\in [0,1]$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and try to calculate a closed form for it. For $a=0$ this is just the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ and for $a=1$ it is the Taylor expansion of $(x+1)^{-(n+1)}$.

I already tried to interpret the sum as a Taylor expansion and was looking for a generalization of $(x+1)^{-(n+1)}$, but without success.

If there is a way, to show at least that the result is positive within the radius of convergence, it would be helpful to.

Comment: Question; Did you actually mean "for $a=0$ it is the Taylor expansion of $(x+1)^{-(n+1)}$" or   " "for $a=1$ it is the Taylor expansion of $(x+1)^{-(n+1)}$"?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this mistake.

Comment: No hope for a closed-form for the $a$ in the given range except for $a=0,1.$  For $a=-1,$ you have a Bessel function.  Asymptotics as $x \to \infty$ might be interesting.